# saving dates and data in rails with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I am using `postgres` and `rails`. I have a hotel `reservation` marketplace app. I am trying to implement `unavailable` `dates` for rooms. So to get the `unavailable dates` from the host i provide a calender for the host to check the dates that is unavailable. So for saving these king of data i add a `json field` to the `table` `room` with `unavailable dates` which might look like this

```
"availability":{"days":[{"available":3,"date":"2017-01-19"},{"available":0,"date":"2017-01-20"},{"available":2,"date":"2017-01-22"},{"available":5,"date":"2017-01-23"}]}
```

**`available` tells the `number` of `rooms` available for that `date`**

Is this ok in the long run? I am bit worried here as this design has the disadvantage of keeping the `json` record of each and every day and some housekeeping for removing the dates from `json` when the day is passed. I cant think of another option here. Is this the only option here? Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

JSON and HSTORE data types are powerful tools for schemaless data but when you are using them for a core piece of data in your application that should be normalized than thats hardly an optimal solution. You will have to deal with data duplication and overly complex and convoluted application code.

What you instead should look at is plain old relational modeling:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
  has_many :reservations, through: :rooms
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotel
  has_many :reservations
end

# check_in - date or datetime
# check_out - date or datetime
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :customer
  has_one :hotel, through: :room
end
```

Here you would use the `reservations` table to store the checkin and checkout times. You would query the `rooms` table or `hotels` with joins on the `reservations` table to check which days are unavailable. There are many ways to do this and its a bit out of scope for this question.

Comment: yes this is a good option. But what if the hotel have recieved bookings from other sources. As its a marketplace app we dont have control over that. All we can do is get the unavailable dates from host and save it somewhere. In that case isnt the above solution irrelevant?

Comment: No, your application should still normalize external data.

Comment: sorry I didnt get the point exactly..Did you mean to get unavailable dates from host and only save that instead of saving a record of each and every day?.. and then use both reservation data(calculated from existing reservations for that date range) and the unavailable dates data(recieved from host) to find availability during booking?

Comment: You don't keep track of when a room is available. You assume that every day is available and then query for when it it booked and get a diff. So no you don't need to create a record for every day. The only thing you need to keep track of is reservations and when a room is unavailable for other reasons.

Comment: yes thats what I meant in previous message. Sorry for the confusion. But my primary question still remains...which is regarding the approach to save the unavailable dates..so json datatype is the way to go right?? or am i wrong.. As from the answer you provided i thought you recommended to stay away from json due to complexities it brings in..  If so how would I approach this kind of problem.a different table with unavailable date  or just stick to json??